# Objective C class cannot find definition for Swift protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Swift protocol, like so:

```
@objc protocol Linkable {
    func presentLink(link: MyLink)
}
```

I also have an Objective-C class that isn't playing nice with this protocol:

```
@protocol Linkable;

@interface MyDetailViewController : MyTableViewController <Linkable>

etc...
```

I have declared the protocol correctly as far as I can tell, the protocol has the `@objc` notation, and I'm putting it into the interface declaration of the Objective C class, but I'm still getting a warning at the line that starts `@interface`.

The warning says: "Cannot find protocol definition for 'Linkable'."

Oddly, it builds and runs, and it works as expected, but why the warning if there's actually no problem with Linkable? Is there a different way to declare the protocol, or to conform to it that would clear the warning?

Is this just one of Xcode's warnings that is poorly phrased, and if so what's actually going on?

**EDIT**

Here is a self-contained sample project with the same error: https://github.com/thinkfishhook/Swift-ObjC_Protocol

Comment: Do you `#import "<YourProjectName>-Swift.h"` in MyDetailViewController.m?

Comment: I do, yes: `#import "MyApp-Swift.h"`

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you provide a *minimal self-contained* example?

Comment: @MartinR - I have edited the post to add a repo with a small standalone project that has the warning. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: it works fine for me. There is a warning that the protocol method is implemented, and when I give it an empty implementation, it builds just fine and there are no more warnings

Comment: @Abizern the sample project does not build cleanly for me after implementing the toy protocol. http://imgur.com/a/27rYF

Comment: I think you need to move your bridging header import to the header file where you are using it instead of the implementation file.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore You can't have the bridging header in the .h file. Xcode says it doesn't exist if imported into .h. It only works for .m files.

Comment: @nickdnk Yep, you're right. Importing from same module into the header could cause a cyclical reference. Swift book says forward declarations of Swift class and protocols can only be used as types for property and method declarations. In order to adopt an ObjC class to a Swift protocol, you need to #import the Xcode-generated header for the Swift code in the .m and use a class extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Protocol_WTF-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController () <MyProtocol>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)doTheThings {
  // doing the things
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate side effect of not being able to import the Swift bridging header file in an Objective-C header.

The code will work just fine as you have found out, so it is safe to suppress the warning with

```objectivec
@protocol Linkable;

// To get rid of 'cannot find protocol definition for' warnings
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol" 
@interface MyDetailViewController : MyTableViewController <Linkable>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```